# Polymer 2.0 menu tabs with content

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer-2.x

I am new to the Google Polymer Project. I just initialize a project to make a custom website design with Polymer. However, i would like to know how to build navbar menu with specific pages. I need to show separate content on the body when we click on each tabs. Any help would be greatly appreciated !!

Here is my code:

```css
iron-image {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<base href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.5.0/lib/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>

<link rel="import" href="paper-styles/classes/global.html">
<link rel="import" href="paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">

<style is="custom-style">
  :root {
    --paper-tabs-selection-bar-color: var(--paper-light-blue-900);
    --paper-tab-ink: var(--paper-light-blue-100);
  
    --paper-tabs: {
      color: white;
      background-color: var(--paper-light-blue-500);
    };
  }
</style>

<paper-tabs selected="0">
  <paper-tab>TAB 1</paper-tab>
  <paper-tab>TAB 2</paper-tab>
  <paper-tab>TAB 3</paper-tab>
</paper-tabs>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8boLeohf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it working you need to use `iron-pages` with `paper-tabs`. Check the updated fiddle.

```js
 var pages = document.querySelector('iron-pages');
     var tabs = document.querySelector('paper-tabs');

    tabs.addEventListener('iron-select', function() { 
        pages.selected = tabs.selected;
    });
```

```css
:root {
  --paper-tabs-selection-bar-color: var(--paper-light-blue-900);
  --paper-tab-ink: var(--paper-light-blue-100);
  --paper-tabs: {
    color: white;
    background-color: var(--paper-light-blue-500);
  }
  ;
}
iron-image {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<base href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.5.0/lib/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>

<link rel="import" href="paper-styles/classes/global.html">
<link rel="import" href="paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
<link rel="import" href="iron-pages/iron-pages.html">

<style is="custom-style">
  :root {
    --paper-tabs-selection-bar-color: var(--paper-light-blue-900);
    --paper-tab-ink: var(--paper-light-blue-100);
  
    --paper-tabs: {
      color: white;
      background-color: var(--paper-light-blue-500);
    };
  }
</style>

<div unresolved vertical layout>
  <paper-tabs selected="0">
    <paper-tab>TAB 1</paper-tab>
    <paper-tab>TAB 2</paper-tab>
    <paper-tab>TAB 3</paper-tab>
  </paper-tabs>
  <iron-pages selected="0">
    <div>Page 1</div>
    <div>Page 2</div>
    <div>Page 3</div>
  </iron-pages>
</div>
```

Comment: my chrome console shows an error "addEventsListener" https://prnt.sc/gt368m

Comment: have you defined variable `tabs` `var tabs = document.querySelector('paper-tabs');`